Equivalent conditions of $\textrm{Ext}^2(A,B) = 0$ for all $A$ and $B$
I am studying homological algebra and I am having difficulty proving the equivalences of the following:
(i) If $0 \to A \xrightarrow{f} B$ is exact and $B$ is projective, then $A$ is projective
(ii) If $B \xrightarrow{g} C \to 0$ is exact and $B$ is injective, then $C$ is injective
(iii) $\textrm{Ext}^2(A,B) = 0$ for all objects $A$ and $B$
I have proven $(iii) \implies (ii)$, but I am struggling to prove $(ii) \implies (i) \implies (iii)$. I know that $B$ is injective iff $\textrm{Hom}(-, B)$ is exact, and that $K$ is projective iff $\textrm{Hom}(K,-)$ is exact. Thus, in my attempt to prove $(ii) \implies (i)$, I started out by an exact sequence $0 \to C \to D \to E \to 0$ and hommed by $B$ in hopes to exploit the exactness of $\textrm{Hom}(-,B)$, but that didn't lead me to a result (perhaps I am missing something). I also don't know how to prove $(i) \implies (iii)$, the difficulty of which results from the fact that we are working for general objects $A$ and $B$, and not just projective objects.

You might want to try proving (iii) $\Rightarrow$ (i), which you can probably do by modifying your proof that (iii) $\Rightarrow$ (ii). Then you might try to prove the converses of each of these. To prove (i) $\Rightarrow$ (iii), for example, start to construct a projective resolution of $A$ by taking $P \to A \to 0$ with $P$ projective, and then look at the kernel.
